# DNS - GoDaddy for mail and AWS for rest

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns-zone, godaddy

I have a GoDaddy hosting account but for some of my websites I would like to host them in AWS S3. My question is how to set DNS entries in Route 53 so that I keep web traffic served from S3 but I point email traffic to GoDaddy?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You set the MX records to point to GoDaddy's e-mail servers.